# Bold text in ObservableList breaks ChangeListener

Tags: java, listview, javafx, observablelist

I want a header in my ObservableList that is bold. I've got it bold but it hits the exception block when it's selected because it is not a string. I can make the other items Text but then the ChangeListener wants a string. I just want the exception to go away.

Is there a way to make it not select-able OR bold and of type string?

```
   ListView<String> list = new ListView<>();
   ObservableList items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   Task curr = tasklist.head;

   items.add(TextBuilder.create().text("Done Tasks").style("-fx-font-weight:bold;").build());
   items.add(curr.name + " - " + curr.description);
   //items.add(new Text(curr.name + " - " + curr.description));

   try {
        list.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov,
                                final String oldvalue, final String newvalue) {
                if(newvalue != "Done Tasks")
                    selectedValue[0] = newvalue.split(" - ")[0];
                else
                    selectedValue[0] = "done";
            }
        });
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        actiontarget.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
        actiontarget.setText("You must select a task.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Quick and Dirty Answer*

To directly answer your wishes "I can make the other items Text but then the ChangeListener wants a string. I just want the exception to go away.", you can change the type of the ChangeListener to accept Object rather than String:

```
new ChangeListener<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Object> observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        if(!(newvalue instanceof Text)) {
            String string = ((String) newvalue).split(" - ")[0];
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I do not recommend the above approach as you lose some of the innate type safety goodness that the Java environment provides.

*Coding Advice*

Some advice based upon your code snippet.

1. Use [cell factories](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#setCellFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) to generate ListView cell nodes from the underlying item model data for the ListView.
2. Don't put nodes such as Text directly into the ListView item list.  The ListView item list is for representing model objects which are not nodes.  I know the [ListView javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) doesn't state this explicitly, but, nevertheless that is still the best recommendation I have.  Whenever you think a node would be a good fit in a ListView, your better option is usually to use a cell factory.
3. When you do place [items](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#itemsProperty) into the ListView, they should match the type of the items of the ListView (the javadoc for ListView does state this).
4. For a non-trivial use case such as you have here, use a more complicated data structure to represent the items in the list, so that you can encode semantic data such as whether or not an item is a header directly into the item rather than hardcoding strings such as "Done Tasks".
5. Don't use the Builder classes, such as TextBuilder, they are deprecated and will be removed from future JavaFX runtime distributions.
6. Use external stylesheets and manipulate styles by setting and unsetting style classes instead of inlining style definitions in code.

*Sample Incorporating Advice*

Based upon the advice you could code your problem up as something like the application below (note it still isn't extracting the style info to an external stylesheet, I'll leave that part as an exercise):

[image: screenshot]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListDisplay extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ListView<TaskItem> listView = new ListView<>(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new TaskItem("Todo Tasks", null, true, true),
                        new TaskItem("Senility", "The Autumn Years", false, false),
                        new TaskItem("Death", "But I didn't eat the salmon mousse", false, false),
                        new TaskItem("Done Tasks", null, true, true),
                        new TaskItem("Birth", "The Miracle of Life", true, false),
                        new TaskItem("School", "Growth and Learning", true, false),
                        new TaskItem("Middle Age", "Stagnation", true, false),
                        new TaskItem("Live Organ Transplants", "The Machine that goes 'Ping'", true, false)
                )
        );

        listView.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<TaskItem>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(TaskItem item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (!empty && item != null) {
                    if (item.isHeader()) {
                        setText(item.getName());
                        setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;");
                    } else {
                        setText(item.getName() + " - " + item.getDescription());
                        setStyle(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    setText(null);
                }
            }
        });

        listView.setPrefHeight(200);

        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (!newValue.isHeader()) {
                System.out.println("Selected: " + newValue.getName());
            }
        });

        stage.setTitle("Monty Python's Meaning of Life");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(listView));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static class TaskItem {
        private final String name;
        private final String description;
        private final SimpleBooleanProperty completed;
        private final boolean header;

        public TaskItem(String name, String description, boolean completed, boolean header) {
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
            this.completed = new SimpleBooleanProperty(completed);
            this.header = header;
        }

        public boolean isHeader() {
            return header;
        }

        public boolean isCompleted() {
            return completed.get();
        }

        public SimpleBooleanProperty completedProperty() {
            return completed;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
    }
}
```